# Paspberry Pi 3 Model B (Gpio command line)

Tags: gpio

I am trying to write a simple program using Pi4J. Them main project is to start a motor. I connected it to a GPIO. 
And then, everything seems that is working fine except for...the pins!

I decided to play a little with the `gpio` in terminal.
First step was `gpio mode 7 out` and then I tried both of the following:

- `gpio write 7 1`
- `while true; do gpio write 7 1; done`

I run the above also with superuser privileges.

The `gpio readall` command sais that I have this pin in `Out Mode` (The `V` column means voltage? And why is it stuck at `0` at `GPIO. 7`?).

```
+-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 |   IN | 1 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 |   IN | 1 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |  OUT | 0 |  7 || 8  | 0 | IN   | TxD     | 15  | 14  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 1 | IN   | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
 |  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |   IN | 0 | 11 || 12 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
 |  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |   IN | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |   IN | 0 | 15 || 16 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
 |  10 |  12 |    MOSI |   IN | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   9 |  13 |    MISO |   IN | 0 | 21 || 22 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
 |  11 |  14 |    SCLK |   IN | 0 | 23 || 24 | 1 | IN   | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 1 | IN   | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
 |   0 |  30 |   SDA.0 |   IN | 1 | 27 || 28 | 1 | IN   | SCL.0   | 31  | 1   |
 |   5 |  21 | GPIO.21 |   IN | 1 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   6 |  22 | GPIO.22 |   IN | 1 | 31 || 32 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.26 | 26  | 12  |
 |  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 |   IN | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  19 |  24 | GPIO.24 |   IN | 0 | 35 || 36 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.27 | 27  | 16  |
 |  26 |  25 | GPIO.25 |   IN | 0 | 37 || 38 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.28 | 28  | 20  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.29 | 29  | 21  |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

The motor and the cables are working (I plugged them at 3.3V).

Is it possible for the pins to be damaged, or disabled? If not, how could I see my motor working?

Here you can find more info about the system

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

and

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.80-v7+ #1098 SMP Fri Mar 9 19:11:42 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I also run `sudo ./x_pigpio` which sais `PASS` at every line and `./gpiotest` which sais

```
Skipped non-user gpios: 0 1 28 29 30 31 
Tested user gpios: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
Failed user gpios: None
```

Comment: I don't know which GPIO or pins you are talking about.  If you have driven a motor using the GPIO you may have destroyed the Pi.  Look at https://pinout.xyz/

Comment: @joan why this could destroy the pi? The motor is 3V-6V. I did something like this (https://hackster.imgix.net/uploads/attachments/328805/breadboard_assembled_rpi2_kit_FGWUBlUwu7.jpg) but with a motor! Instead of 3.3V I plugged it in GPIO. 7. I also run some tests (see edit)

Comment: You need to edit the question and tell us what you have done.  Saying you did something like something else does not help.  Without knowing what you have done it's not possible to know if you have damaged the Pi or not.

Comment: I connected a motor at GPIO. 7 and I would like to start it using the gpio command line tool. That's what I want to make a start.

Comment: If we accept what you say at face value you will destroy your Pi.  You need to use a motor driver board or implement the equivalent using transistors and diodes.

Comment: what does this mean? `I connected it to a GPIO (0,1 is ok since I just to want to start it)`

Comment: @jsotola I used any pin and no a pwm one because I want only to see it running.

Comment: then change that line to `I connected it to a GPIO` .... the part in the brackets does not add any information, it just adds confusion to your description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `v`  column means Digital Value (Raspberry Pi has not analog GPIO ports), `0` means off and `1` means on

So, you have the GPIO 7. on `OUT` mode and it's turned off (`0` on Digital)

About the motors, Raspberry Pi was not done to connect motors to it, so maybe you destroyed the GPIO, see the motor capacity and see if it is more or less than the Raspberry Pi,

You can use a external font to give energy to the motors and use a H bridge to connect to the Raspberry Pi; this way is less dangerous.

Comment: but is ever better to use Terminal

Comment: To add more info the GPIO pins are inadequate to start a motor, due to small amperage.  I need more power from the VDC pins of the Pi. That's something I did know about!

Comment: @LiTTle You can use a 5V Relay connected to the RPi